# PostgreSQL window function: grouping by column without ordering (~ Python itertools.groupby)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to partition a table in PostgreSQL based on a column without sorting & making the result unique; Basically what I am trying to achieve is to reproduce the `itertools.groupby()` behavior from Python in PostgreSQL.

Given the table containing two columns:

```
1   C
2   C
3   C
4   C
5   C
6   C
7   C
8   C
9   C
10  S
11  E
12  E
13  E
14  E
15  E
16  C
17  C
18  C
19  C
20  E
21  E
22  E
23  E
24  E
```

I want to partition it by the value in the second (whilst preserving the existing order), to end up with this:

```
1   C   1
2   C   1
3   C   1
4   C   1
5   C   1
6   C   1
7   C   1
8   C   1
9   C   1
10  S   2
11  E   3
12  E   3
13  E   3
14  E   3
15  E   3
16  C   4
17  C   4
18  C   4
19  C   4
20  E   5
21  E   5
22  E   5
23  E   5
24  E   5
```

I tried to achieve that with window functions, using a combination of `ROW_NUMBER()` and `LAG()` to compare the current row with the previous to see if it has changed. The problem in that case was that I would also need a variable that increments every time the value changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH T1 AS
(
    SELECT
        id,
        grp,
        LAG(grp) OVER (ORDER BY id) IS DISTINCT FROM grp AS changes
    FROM yourtable
)
SELECT id, grp, SUM(changes::int) OVER (ORDER BY id) FROM T1
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you *can* come up with a solution based entirely on window functions, this kind of stateful processing of the result set seems best suited to an iterative approach. Here's a question that asked something a bit similar before: [PostgreSQL function to iterate through/act on many rows with state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001550/postgresql-function-to-iterate-through-act-on-many-rows-with-state/3001869#3001869)

Basically the window-only approach comes down to producing an integer column with a "1" (or any other positive integer) at the start of each partition (so where `col2<>LAG(col2)`) and then using another window aggregation to sum those group indicators from the start of the result set up to the current row. It works, it's just ugly both in complexity and (I believe) in performance.